# Is improving one's middot a mitzvah?

Tags: mussar-ethics

Is having good middot, such as being mevater, a mitzvah? By that I mean: Is there a Biblical commandment to improve one's middot?

Comment: See Ohr Someach, Hilchos Talmud Torah, Perek 1, Halachah 2, d"h Be'Yuma

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sefer Hachinuch Mitsva 611

> מצוה ללכת ולהדמות בדרכי השם יתברך - שנצטוינו לעשות כל מעשינו בדרך הישר
> והטוב בכל כחנו, ולהטות כל דברינו אשר בינינו ובין זולתנו, על דרך החסד
> והרחמים, כאשר ידענו מתורתנו שזהו דרך השם וזה חפצו מבריותיו, למען יזכו
> לטובו כי חפץ חסד הוא, ועל זה נאמר (דברים כח ט) והלכת בדרכיו, ונכפלה
> המצוה עוד במקום אחר, שנאמר ללכת בכל דרכיו (דברים י, יב; יא, כב).
>
> The commandment to walk in - and make oneself similar through - the
> ways of God, may He be blessed: That we were commanded to perform all
> our actions in the way of straightness and goodness with all our
> strength and to incline all our affairs that are between ourselves and
> others towards the way of kindness and mercy; as we have known from
> our holy Torah that this is the way of God, and this is God’s desire
> for His creatures so that they merit God’s goodness - as He desires
> kindness. And about this is it stated (Deuteronomy 28:9), "and you
> shall walk in His ways." And this commandment was further repeated in
> another place, as it is stated (Deuteronomy 10:12, 11:22), "to walk in
> all His ways."

The Chinuch follows almost exclusively the Sefer Hamitsvot from Rambam, there this is the Mitsva 8:

> היא שצונו להדמות בו יתעלה כפי היכולת והוא אמרו והלכת בדרכיו. וכבר נכפל
> זה הצווי ואמר ללכת בכל דרכיו ובא בפירוש (סוטה י"ד) מה הקב"ה נקרא חנון
> אף אתה היה חנון מה הקב"ה נקרא רחום אף אתה היה רחום מה הקב"ה נקרא חסיד
> אף אתה היה חסיד. וכבר נכפל זה הענין בלשון אחר ואמר אחרי ה' תלכו ובא
> בפירוש שרצה לומר ההדמות בפעולותיו הטובות והמדות הנכבדות שיתואר בהם האל
> יתעלה על צד המשל. יתעלה על הכל עילוי רב. (בפרשת והיה כי תבא, מדע הלכות
> דעות):
>
> That is that He commanded us to imitate Him, may He be exalted,
> according to our ability. And that is His saying, "and you shall go in
> His ways" (Deuteronomy 28:9). And this command has already been
> repeated, [when] He said, "and to go in all of His ways" (Deuteronomy
> 11:22). And in the explanation, it appears (Sifrei Devarim 49:1),
> "Just as the Holy One, blessed be He, is called "merciful," you too,
> be merciful. Just as the Holy One, blessed be He, is called pious, you
> too, be pious." And this matter was already repeated in different
> words: He said, "Go in the ways of the Lord." And in the explanation,
> it appears (Sotah 14a) that He meant to say to imitate His good deeds
> and glorious traits by which God, may He be exalted, is described, by
> way on analogy - He is exalted over everything with great exaltation.
> (See Parashat Ki Tavo; Mishneh Torah, Human Dispositions.)

Comment: I would add just references to Rambam Hilkhos Dei'os, the koter tells you that the first mitzvah it addresses is this one. Also point to the "chovos" in Chovos haLvavos.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Sifri (Divarim 49)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Devarim.49.1?lang=bi&with=Deuteronomy&lang2=en) having proper midos is how to fulfill the mitzva of emulating Hashem:

> כִּי֩ אִם־שָׁמֹ֨ר תִּשְׁמְר֜וּן אֶת־כָּל־הַמִּצְוָ֣ה הַזֹּ֗את אֲשֶׁ֧ר אָנֹכִ֛י מְצַוֶּ֥ה אֶתְכֶ֖ם לַעֲשֹׂתָ֑הּ לְאַהֲבָ֞ה אֶת־יְהוָ֧ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶ֛ם לָלֶ֥כֶת בְּכָל־דְּרָכָ֖יו וּלְדָבְקָה־בֽוֹ׃
>
> If, then, you faithfully keep all this Instruction that I command you, loving the LORD your God, walking in all His ways, and holding fast to Him,
>
> ללכת בכל דרכיו - אלו דרכי הקב"ה, שנ' (שמות לד) ה' ה' אל רחום וחנון, ארץ אפים ורב חסד ואמת, נוצר חסד לאלפים, נושא עון ופשע וחטאה ונקה. ואו' (יואל ג) כל אשר יקרא בשם ה' ימלט. וכי היאך אפשר לו לאדם להיקרא בשמו של הקב"ה? אלא מה המקום נקרא רחום וחנון - אף אתה הוי רחום וחנון ועשה מתנת חנם לכל. מה הקב"ה נקרא צדיק, שנ' (תהלים קמה) צדיק ה' בכל דרכיו וחסיד בכל מעשיו - אף אתה הוי צדיק. הקב"ה נקרא חסיד, שנאמ' וחסיד בכל מעשיו - אף אתה הוי חסיד; לכך נאמר כל אשר יקרא בשם ה' ימלט, ואומר (ישעיה מג) כל הנקרא בשמי ולכבודי בראתיו, יצרתיו אף עשיתיו, ואו' (משלי טז) כל פעל ה' למענהו:
>
> (Devarim 11:22) "to walk in His ways": Which are the ways of the Holy One Blessed be He? (Shemoth 34:6-7) "The L-rd, the L-rd, G-d of mercy and grace, slow to wrath and abundant in mercy and truth, keeping lovingkindness for thousands, forgiving transgression, offense, and sin, and cleansing …" And it is written (Yoel 3:5) "All who will be called by the name of the L-rd will escape": Now how is it possible for a man to be called by the name of the Holy One Blessed be He? But, (the intent is) just as the L-rd is called "merciful and gracious," you, too, be merciful and gracious, and give gratuitously to all. Just as the Holy One Blessed be He is called "righteous," viz. (Psalms 145:17) "Righteous is the L-rd in all His ways and saintly in all His acts" — you, too, be righteous. Just as the Holy One Blessed be He is called "saintly," — you, too, be saintly. This is the intent of "All who will be called by the name of the L-rd will escape." And it is written (Isaiah 43:7) "… everyone that is called by My name. For My honor I have created him, and formed him, and fashioned him." And it is written (Proverbs 16:4) "The L-rd has created all for His sake." (Devarim, Ibid.)

This is emphasized in the [introduction to Mesilas Yesharim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Messilat_Yesharim%2C_Introduction.31?lang=bi&lang2=en) as being one of the five categories of service of Hashem, separate from the performance of individual mitzvos:

> הוא מה שמשה רבנו, עליו השלום, מלמדנו באמרו (דברים י יב): ועתה ישראל מה ה' אלקיך שואל מעמך, כי אם ליראה את ה' אלקיך ללכת בכל דרכיו ולאהבה אותו ולעבוד את ה' אלקיך בכל לבבך ובכל נפשך, לשמור את מצות ה' ואת חקתיו.
> כאן כלל כל חלקי שלמות העבודה הנרצית לשמו יתברך, והם: היראה, ההליכה בדרכיו, האהבה, שלמות הלב, ושמירת כל המצות.
>
> This is what Moshe, our teacher, peace be unto him, teaches us saying: "And now, Israel, what does the L-rd your G-d ask of you, but that you fear the L-rd your G-d to walk in all His ways, and to love Him and serve the L-rd your G-d with all your heart and all your soul, to keep the mitzvot (commandments) of G-d and His statutes..." (Deut. 10:12)
> Here he encompassed all the divisions of perfection of divine service that is desirable to the blessed G-d. They are: fear [of G-d], walking in His ways, love [of G-d], wholeheartedness, and observance of all of the commandments.

> ההליכה בדרכיו כולל כל ענין יושר המדות ותקונם. והוא מה שביארו ז"ל (שבת קל"ג): מה הוא רחום אף אתה רחום וכו'. וכלל כל זה שינהג האדם כל מדותיו וכל מיני פעולותיו על פי היושר והמוסר.
>
> Walking in His ways - this includes all matters of uprightness and correction of character traits. This is what our sages of blessed memory explained (Shab.133b) "just as He is merciful, be also merciful..." The general principle of all this is for one to conduct all of his traits in all the variety of his deeds according to what is just and ethical.

Answer (score 3):

A number of sources mention the importance of tikkun hamiddos but principally to give us lowly humans the ability to gain a closer connection to G-d and not as a mitzvah in isolation. By that I mean, it is considered vitally important, but is to be regarded more as being foundational for all our spiritual actions. We are all born with imperfections, so when we strive to correct these failings we are making ourselves more spiritually sound.

In the [introduction](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim%2C_Introduction.19?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) to Orchos Tzaddikim it notes how the improvement of middos is what our whole mitzvah performance is predicated on. Yet, it does not mention it as its own mitzvah.

> וכשאין בידך מידות טובות – אין בידך תורה ומצוות, **כי כל התורה תלויה בתיקון המידות**. כי כל המידות טובות ורעות – החכם יכול לעשות הרעות לטובות, והכסיל יעשה מידות טובות לרעות. ומי שהולך בחושך ואינו מתבונן בתיקון המידות, אפשר שיהא בו מידה המאבדת כל זכויותיו. כגון המתגאה במעשיו, ומתפאר ומייפה עצמו תמיד בגנות של חברו ומתכבד בקלונו. והאיש ההוא דומה למי שממלא חבית יין משובח, ויש בתחתית החבית נקב קטן – אין ספק שיאבד כל היין המשובח בנקב הקטן אם לא יסתום אותו. כך המתגאה הזה: אף על פי שהוא מלא תורה, יאבד הכל על ידי המידה הרעה הזאת אם לא יחוש לתקנה
>
> And when you have no good qualities within you then you have neither Torah nor Commandments. **For the whole Torah depends on the constant improvement of the qualities**. As regards the qualities, the good and the bad, the wise man can make good ones of bad ones but the fool can make evil qualities out of good ones. As for him who walks in the darkness, and does not consider the improvement of his qualities, it is possible that one quality will destroy all of his merit. For example, one who takes great pride in his deeds and boasts and preens himself always with the shame of his companions, and seeks to obtain honor through his companion's disgrace, such a man is like one who fills a barrel with fine wine, but there is in the bottom of the barrel a little hole. There is no doubt that all of the fine wine will be lost because of the small hole, if he does not stop it up. So this man who is arrogant, even though he is filled with Torah, will lose everything through this evil quality if he does not hasten to repair it.

So we see from Orchos Tzaddikim that our whole Torah observance is predicated on tikkun hamiddos. It is not necessarily a mitzvah in isolation, but is the basis through which we are able to grow spiritually through the prism of mitzvos and the like.

Rambam in [Moreh Nevuchim 3:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.35.4?vhe=Moreh_Nevuchim,_translated_by_Ibn_Tibon&lang=bi) without specifying exactly what they actually are, classes a whole group of mitzvos based on rectifying middos. So again, it is not its own mitzvah but a vital quality for mitzvah performance. He write there:

> **הכלל השלישי כולל ה'מצוות' התלויות בתיקון המידות** והם אשר ספרנום ב"הלכות דעות". וידוע שבטוב המדות תשלם חברת בני אדם וקיבוציהם אשר הוא הכרחי לסידור עניני בני אדם:
>
> **The third class is formed by commandments which are connected with the improvement of the moral condition [of mankind]; these are mentioned in Hilkot de‘ot**. It is known that by a good moral state those social relations, which are indispensable for the well-being of mankind, are brought to perfection.

Once again, it would seem that it is not necessarily an inherent mitzvah but rather a pre-requisite for spiritual growth. If we want to grow in our levels of holiness and get close to G-d then it can only come through rectifying and improving our own character failings.

This too is echoed by the [Sfas Emes on Shemini 15:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Leviticus%2C_Shmini.15.2?lang=bi) where he notes that the Jewish people, prior to Matan Torah had to spend time fixing their middos and purifying themselves so that they were in a fit state to receive the Torah. Again, it would seem that it is a crucial step to practising mitzvos but not a mitzvah in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to explain the role of Mussar in Yahadus.

1- Correcting one's Middos is a mitzvah. As Kouty's answer notes, it is in the Seifer haChinukh as mitzvah #611. In the Rambam's Code, Hilkhos Dei'os, on the introduction which lists which mitzvos the section covers, this is the first mitzvah. Both based on the Sifri that Mordechai's answer quotes, as they cite the verse the Sifri is on -- "והלכת בדרכין / and you shall go in His Ways."

So the answer is "yes", but that's not the only role correcting middos has.

2- Correcting one's Middos is necessary if you want to be capable of better performing other mitzvos. So, just as the mitzvah of Sukkah obligates trying to have a Sukkah available come Sukkos, so does every mitzvah that I currently find challenging include working on my Middos beforehand so that I make the right decision more often when the moment comes. Mussar as a hekhsher mitzvah (prep for a mitzvah) for many different mitzvos doesn't make it one of the 613 itself, but it does make it obligatory.

3- One of the key issues that split hashkafos in Eastern Europe in the period between the Englightenment and the Shoah was the question of what mitzvos are all about. Chassidus taught that their ultimate goal was deveiqus, to bond to Hashem. Lithuanian Judaism is founded on the idea that the ultimate goal was sheleimus (wholeness) or temimus (perfection).

(And then the Mussar and Yeshiva movements split over whether one has to actively work on sheleimus and temimus on ways beyond Torah study and performing mitzvos.)

Both approaches have a far longer history. For example, we mentioned the Chinukh... He explains aspects of the Divine Motive for each mitzvah. The Chinukh repeatedly invokves the idea "האדם נפעל לפי פעולןתיו -- a person is affected according to their actions." He understands the role of mitzvos as character building.

And this is the Orchos Tzadiqim's approach in Dov's answer.

If one takes this approach to mitzvos, then it is less that Middah work is one of the mitzvos, which it is, but that mitzvos exist as exercises in Middah work!

Comment: Is there a way to tag the people whose answers I cite?

Comment: unfortunately no, though you can comment on those answers to recommend they check yours out